# jquery slider that calls a function always off by 1 until handle is released

Tags: jquery, slider

I've asked this question before and am surprised nobody can help me.  You can see exactly what I am attempting here http://training.mercury.stellarbluewebdesign.com/GainOil/ You will notice that the update to the values on the top aren't correct until the handle is released.  I am told that I have to use ui.value in the function that calculates them but nobody seems to know exactly how.  The jquery code is here http://training.mercury.stellarbluewebdesign.com/GainOil/js/functions.js

Answer (score 0):

The 'slide' event you are calling is passing you the new value in:

> var value = ui.value;

this is not what the actual value is set as yet though.   Its not until you release the mouse, or move on again that the value is set.

If you add :

```
var realval = $( ".slider" ).slider( "option", "value" );
console.log(realval);
```

into your slide event function it will return the number that is being used to perform the calculations.

You should add a parameter to calculate_savings function you could pass it through to perform that calculation.   but based on the number of sliders you have, that could be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your code to change the values on the right side...

```
    // hook all sliders to their span.value (display)
$( '.slider' ).bind( 'slide', function( e, ui )
{   
    var field = $( this ).attr( 'field' );
    var value = ui.value;
    var $matchingElem = $( '.value[field="' + field + '"]' )
    var decimals = $matchingElem.attr( 'decimals' ) || 0
    $matchingElem.text( addCommas( value ) )
    calculate_savings();

} ).bind( 'slidechange', function()
{
    calculate_savings();
} ) // Ps. your missing a semicolon in your original script here <<<<
```

Why bind the calculate savings separately?? Wouldnt this work instead?

```
        // hook all sliders to their span.value (display)
$( '.slider' ).bind( 'slide', function( e, ui )
{   
    var field = $( this ).attr( 'field' );
    var value = ui.value;
    var $matchingElem = $( '.value[field="' + field + '"]' )
    var decimals = $matchingElem.attr( 'decimals' ) || 0
    $matchingElem.text( addCommas( value ) )
    calculate_savings();

} );
```

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone that took the time to help me fix this problem.  I used Matt's approach.

Answer (score 0):

inKit is correct. The "slide" event is forecasting the change in value that **will** occur if the callback function doesn't cancel it (for example by returning false). While it isn't ideal for your use-case, programming it this way gives the developer the ability to choose wether or not to allow the slide event to go through; Unfortunately this means that at the time your callback function is being run, the value has not actually been updated yet.

I think inKit's suggestion to modify the calculate_savings function so it can handle passing in the "future" value for the specific slider being changed is probably the stronger solution, but it may require more refactoring than you're interested in tackling.

An alternative would be to break your calculate_savings call out of the callback cycle with a 0 millisecond setTimeout.

Here is the pertinent portion of your code:

```
// hook all sliders to their span.value (display)
$( '.slider' ).bind( 'slide', function( e, ui )
{    
    var field = $( this ).attr( 'field' );
    var value = ui.value;
    var $matchingElem = $( '.value[field="' + field + '"]' )
    var decimals = $matchingElem.attr( 'decimals' ) || 0
    $matchingElem.text( addCommas( value ) )

    // Allow the slide event time to complete successfully and update the slider's value before calculating the savings.
    setTimeout(function(){calculate_savings();},0);
} )
```

The new code in action can be seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/maXcs/1/

*Note: With the updating now working as expected the slidechange bind can now be removed per VIDesignz's suggestion.*